# Nested scroll view elements are not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

I have relative layout in nested scroll view and under relative layout I have view pager tablayout and recycler view. My problem is nested scroll view elements are not scrolling view pager is fixed on top while recycler view is scrolling below view pager.I want to scroll view pager also in layout.

This is my code below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".Home"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linearHome"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="12dp"
android:paddingRight="12dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress2"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/nobook"
    android:src="@drawable/nobook"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/homeOffers"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/homeOffers"
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/indicator"
        android:id="@+id/refresh">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycle"/>

   </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>

  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Someone please let me know how to get desired layout. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Try to add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in your RecyclerView. You can also try to add `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` in your code.

Comment: App:layout_behavior I have already added in nested scroll view.

Comment: Bro its not working...

Answer (score 0):

You can change your parent layout and use ScrollView as a child.

**Your current layout:**
{NestedScrollView}*(Which is your parent)* -->
{RelativeLayout} -->
{ProgressBar,
 ImageView,
ViewPager etc}

**After changing your parent to the relative layout :**
{RelativeLayout}*(Which is now your new parent layout. Everything else remains the same)*-->
{ScrollView}*(which preveously was your NestedScrollView)* -->
{RelativeLayout} -->
{ProgressBar,
 ImageView,
ViewPager etc}

Comment: I have changed my layout as suggested by you  but no luck so far.

Comment: As I remove swipe refresh layout it works fine but after including swipe refresh layout it stops scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Try this - app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" property to the SwipeRefreshLayout.

Comment: Nope its not working actually the culprit is swipe refresh layout after removing it everything works fine but as i add this it stops scrolling but I need to include swipe refresh layout in my layout.